# A permutation considering one item has to be prior to another

Tags: python-2.7, python-itertools

I have a problem regarding the permutation problem.

I have a list of (1,2,3,4,5,6), then if I apply the following code:

```
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6],6))
```

I would get 720 permutations. Instead, I have a specific sequence that:
1 has to be ahead of 5,
2 has to be ahead of 6,
3 has to be ahead of 7,
4 has to be ahead of 8,
so does anyone know how to generate permutations consider the rules above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You create your permutations and filter them:

```
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8))

# your rules for filter 
def IsOk(tupl):
    one = tupl.index(1)
    two = tupl.index(2)
    thr = tupl.index(3)
    fou = tupl.index(4)
    fiv = tupl.index(5)
    six = tupl.index(6)
    sev = tupl.index(7)
    eig = tupl.index(8)
    return one > fiv and two > six and thr > sev and fou > eig

print(a)

filtered = filter(lambda x: IsOk(x), a)

print(*filtered)
print(len(*filtered))
```

I had to increase your permutations to 8 so all your rules could be processed.

This reduces the permutations from 40320 down to 2520.